# Need help with a clean Normal map for a character in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, baking, normal-map

First of all thank you for your time reading this.

I am new to Blender and I managed to make my very first character.
my low poly mesh has been created and I sculpt one for more defined details.

[image]

But the problem is, I can not seem to fix the baking process to get a nice blue normal map, and I am not experienced enough to know how to fix this.

[image]

Some of these parts are inside the mouth, so can I just remove them?
Since I will be using textures for the teeth and tongue and mouth in general.

I think my main problem is with overlapping meshes.
Does any more experienced blender artists know how to deal with this?
And can take a look at my file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecoxbtog60wwc6h/Ossy.blend?dl=0

This character will be used in animation so maybe this isn't all necessarily.
Thank you all for your time and I hope to hear from anyone soon.

Comment: Baking a Normal map? Try Ray Distance, down here in the answer! This will may help.

Comment: Hello Jayem14, I have try'd the ray distance many times, the issue's are between the toes where the ray intersect I believe  so even with a low setting it does not work sadly, thank you for the help.

I think that my low poly mesh is sometimes bigger then the detailed one and vice versa.

Comment: **_This_** happens when people try mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMqgD.png), around 7.30 he addresses the issue, which is that it is baking the wrong side of the faces. It can often be fixed with the "ray distance" settings, under the bake menu. Try changing this to 0.1 or 0.2 to see if it fixes the problem.

[image: [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch]

Comment: Hello sorenfrostsaal,

Thank you for the help, but the Ray distance is not the issue sadly, I try with different distances, 0.05 got the best results for me.

I think the Issue has more to do with overlapping meshes since I sculpted some stuff inwards the low poly mesh.

Comment: Okay, how about scaling the low poly mesh to be a tad smaller, and then apply the scale. CTRL+A. and re-bake?

Comment: I shall give it a try, if that doesn't work, I shall try the explosion option.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the overlapping geometry is rendered in the baking process, there's a method called explosion when you do baking, which consider you taking apart each element of your mesh. Here's a example:

[image]

Since your model is simple, you can do this manually, by duplicating your model, and separating each mesh element, you can do this easily by pressing L on edit mode, which will select entire elements, and move them apart. After you done this, test to bake it again and see if you get the clear results you're after.

After you have your map baked, you can delete the exploded mesh and return to the original one, finally applying the normal map.

Would recommend you to Apply Rot & Scale (CTRL+A+Apply Rot & Scale in object mode), and make Normals Consistent (CTRL+N in edit mode) before your baking process, generally many problems can be fixed with this.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I shall give it a try!
Do I apply explosion on the high detail mesh, or on the low poly mesh?

Comment: Both of them, so you can bake the high poly onto the lowpoly. You can offset them by giving for example, +10 in X or -5 in Z, to put the together easily.

Comment: I found a solution, the baking did work but glitches out by some small parts, I am just going to clean up those parts in photoshop. I am not gonna use the mouth so i dont need that in the normal map, plush i adjusted some seams so it would fold flat better, thanks again for the advice!